# How do I generate C# code from WADL files?

Tags: c#, web-services, code-generation, wadl

I am looking for a code generator than can generate C# code to access RESTful web services described by [WADL files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) in a way similar to how [wadl2java](https://wadl.dev.java.net/wadl2java.html) works.

Doing som searching I came across the [rest-api-code-gen](http://code.google.com/p/rest-api-code-gen/) project on Google Code, but although the latest source does in fact support C#, the [REST Describe & Compile demo site](http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html) does not. (The C# button is there, but it's disabled.)

I realize I could download the source and set up my own server with the latest version, but I would prefer not to, as what I need is a command line tool and not a web application with dependencies to Google Web Toolkit. I guess I could write my own a command line tool based on the same source code, but if it has already been done, or other tools can do the job, I'd rather avoid it.

So, I'm wondering, are there any tools like that out there?

Answer (score 2):

There is no normal tool for C# and WADL. rest-api-code-gen project seems to be not developing anymore. And may be in future nothing will be changed. There is no definitive opinion about need of WADL for REST and it's non standard like a WSDL

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer: http://code.google.com/p/rest-api-code-gen/