# How to consume rest service in WCF that was generated with NetBeans?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, rest

I've created a rest service from a mysql database with NetBeans and I want to consume the service in C#, with WCF if possible.

Is there a decent way to generate entities from the WADL file that I can use in Visual Studio and call the rest service methods?

What is the best way to consume the rest service created with NetBeans using Microsoft technology ?

It would have been nice if I could do the same with the WADL as with the WSDL in Visual Studio, to add a service reference...

I've found a tool called WADL.exe for generating entities for c# from the WADL file but it didn't work.

Please help !

Comment: Would any of the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126448/how-do-i-generate-c-code-from-wadl-files) question be of help to you?